# os.Listdir(".") is not returning the contents of the current directory (Python)

Tags: python

When I use `os.listdir(".")` I expect to get the files/folders from the directory that I am currently in *(aka the one that contains the .py file from which the function is being called)*.

That is not what happens, instead I get the files/folders from the "grandparent" directory. as shown below:
[Directory structure, code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsXm7.png)

##### File Structure:

```
grandparent_directory                         
 ╘ parent_directory 
    ╘ script.py                      
    ╘ brother_file
 ╘ uncle_directory
```

##### Code

```
from os import listdir
print(listdir("."))
```

#### Output

```
['parent_directory', 'uncle_dir']
```

This also happens with `listdir()` and `listdir(".")` and any other relative path that you use. And it also seems to be consistent, so it is easy to adapt around it. I just can't figure it out why that's the case.

Comment: The folder where your file is and the current working directory can be different. How do you start your script?

Comment: `.` is the *working* directory, the active directory when you launch Python, it has nothing to do with the directory the script is in unless you `cd`-ed to the same directory as the script up front. `__file__` would tell you the location of the file you ask for it in.